# How to dynamically increment an apk version code in Android?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, fastlane

Right now my the app in the `internal track` has a version code of `565800002` and that in `production` has a version code of `291302934` which comes from the `CircleCI build number * 100,000`.

I would like to increment both version code numbers

- `internal` and `production`
- programmatically, especially the one on `internal`, but I'm stuck on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any groovy function or def to build your version code programmatically.

For ex,

```
**
 * Use the number of seconds/10 since Dec 12 2017 as the versionCode.
 * This lets us upload a new build at most every 10 seconds for the
 * next 680 years.
 */
def verCode = (int) (((new Date().getTime() / 1000) - 1513056598) / 10)
```

Then in your `defaultConfig` block, you can use,

```
versionCode verCode
```

Comment: but I also need to take into account the existing version codes that are currently on the play store:

```
internal : 565800002. * how can I change this number programatically?
production: 291302934
```