# Editing part of text with macOS terminal commands (with terminal commands only)

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, terminal, fastlane

I have a class where I get the `versionCode` as below.

```
object Dev: Variants {
     override val versionCode = 7
     override val versionName = "1.0"
}
```

I want to automatically increase the versionCode value here using `Fastlane` for `Android`. I think `iOS` has support for this but `Android` doesn't.

It occurred to me to increase the `versionCode` value here with the terminal commands I will run through `Fastlane`. (Separate from the topic; I'll git commit with terminal commands later)

On `macOS` for example `nano Dev.kt` opens the file and I can edit it with the keyboard. But how can I change and save the `versionCode` field with purely terminal codes?

Comment: There seem to be a few answers on [so] already when I look at the `fastlane` tag, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67717807/589259) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56199425/589259). Are you sure the answer is not there?

Comment: In the links you posted, groovy vs. This is done with. However, I want to do it with fastlane or terminal codes.